# Passing data from one listview to another

Tags: android

I have been trying to pass the contact data from my second activity's list view to my main activity's list view, upon clicking the checkbox.But the data doesn't get transferred. How do I fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.artist.sender;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.R.id.input;
import static android.app.AlertDialog.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText itemText;
Button addButton;
Button sendText;
TextView text;
Button contact;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    itemText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(itemText.getText())||(itemText.getText().length()<10)||(itemText.getText().length()>10)) {
                itemText.setError("The number is not valid.");
                return;
            } else {
                text.setText(itemText.getText().toString());
                itemText.setText("");
                return;
            }
        }
    });
    Button delete;
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      int con=text.getLineCount();
                                      if(con==0)
                                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No number available to delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     else
                                         text.setText("");
                                  }
                              });
    sendText=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    sendText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String phoneno = text.getText().toString();
            int count = text.getLineCount();
            SmsManager smsMgrVar = SmsManager.getDefault();
            if (count == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No number available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {
                        try{

                            smsMgrVar.sendTextMessage(phoneno, null, "Hey There!", null, null);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ErrVar)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message Sending Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            ErrVar.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 10);
                        }
                    }

                }
    });
    contact =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

    contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,contacts.class));
            }

        }
    });
    String tempholder=getIntent().getStringExtra("Listviewclickvalue");
    text.setText(tempholder);
}
```

}

**contacts.java**

```
package com.example.artist.sender;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;

public class contacts extends MainActivity {
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 444;
private ListView mListView;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private Handler updateBarHandler;

ArrayList<String> contactList;
Cursor cursor;
int counter;
ListView list;
String temp;
TextView itemText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(contacts.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    updateBarHandler = new Handler();

    // Since reading contacts takes more time, let's run it on a separate thread.
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            getContacts();
        }
    }).start();

    // Set onclicklistener to the list item.
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            //TODO Do whatever you want with the list data
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "item clicked : \n" + contactList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getContacts();
        }
    }
}

public void getContacts() {

    if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
        return;
    }

    contactList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String phoneNumber = null;
    // String email = null;

    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

   /* Uri EmailCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
    String EmailCONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID;
    String DATA = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA;*/

    StringBuffer output;

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    // Iterate every contact in the phone
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

        counter = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            output = new StringBuffer();

            // Update the progress message
            updateBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.setMessage("Reading contacts : " + counter++ + "/" + cursor.getCount());
                }
            });

            String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                output.append("\n First Name:" + name);


                //This is to read multiple phone numbers associated with the same contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                    output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);

                }

                phoneCursor.close();

               /* // Read every email id associated with the contact
                Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(EmailCONTENT_URI, null, EmailCONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contact_id}, null);

                while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {

                    email = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(DATA));

                    output.append("\n Email:" + email);

                }

                emailCursor.close();

                String columns[] = {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.MIMETYPE,
                };*/

                String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY +
                        " and " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' and " + ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contact_id;

                String[] selectionArgs = null;
                String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

                /*Cursor birthdayCur = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, columns, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
                Log.d("BDAY", birthdayCur.getCount()+"");
                if (birthdayCur.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (birthdayCur.moveToNext()) {
                        String birthday = birthdayCur.getString(birthdayCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
                        output.append("Birthday :" + birthday);
                        Log.d("BDAY", birthday);
                    }
                }
                birthdayCur.close();
            }*/

                // Add the contact to the ArrayList
                contactList.add(output.toString());
            }

            // ListView has to be updated using a ui thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contact_text, R.id.text1, contactList);
                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

            // Dismiss the progressbar after 500 millisecondds
            updateBarHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pDialog.cancel();
                }
            }, 500);
        }

    }


    //passing the number to the mainactivity's textview through intent
    list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    final String listview[] = new String[list.getCount()];
    for (int j = 0; j < list.getCount(); j++) {
        View v = list.getChildAt(j);
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        listview[j] = (String) tv.getText();
    }
    itemText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    final String number = itemText.getText().toString();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, listview);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                        if ((number.matches("[0-9]+"))&&(number.length()==10))
                                            temp = listview[position].toString();
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(contacts.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("Listviewclickvalue", temp);
                                        startActivity(intent);

                                    }
                                }
    );
}
```

}

**logcat**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.artist.sender/com.example.artist.sender.contacts}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

This is the logcat for the error. It keeps showing that the setitemOnClickListener keeps referring to a null object whereas, I've already assigned the listview to its respective id.

**EDIT:**I've fixed part of the error, by renaming the *setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);* in the contacts class to *setContentView(R.layout.contacts);* But now after that, it shows this error, **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference**

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the database, or some other storage, only pass the _id or the location, respectively.

Instead of passing many extras, Android way is, actually, Parcable. Here a nice tutorial from [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html)

public class TestModel implements Parcelable {

```
String name;
String phoneNumber;

//.....

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.phoneNumber);    
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<TestModel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TestModel>() {
    @Override
    public TestModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new TestModel(source);
    }

    @Override
    public TestModel[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TestModel[size];
    }
};
}
```